# WEKA software analysis for calculating total accuracy

Tags: data-mining, weka

Hi i am using WEKA to analyze some data. But i am having problem how to calculate the **total accuracy** from the output data.

The partial output is bellow

Detailed Accuracy By Class

```
           TP Rate   FP Rate   Precision   Recall  F-Measure   ROC Area  Class
             0.85      0.415      0.794     0.85      0.821      0.762    tested_negative
             0.585     0.15       0.676     0.585     0.627      0.762    tested_positive
```

Weighted Avg.    0.758     0.323      0.753     0.758     0.754      0.762

From the above what will the total accuracy?

Answer (score 1):

What's your confusion matrix from WEKA output?

In general case, it is necessary to know it to calculate accuracy.

And yes, I think "total accuracy" in this case means this accuracy: 
http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/8/5/f/85fb106488e3cb8c02e397c917222ad4.png
(from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision)

Comment: Thakns a lot..So accuracy means total accruacy?

Comment: Here is my confusion matrix http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23104503/weka-software-analysis-of-confusion-matrix

Comment: Then accuracy for the first classifier is: a1 = (349+124)/(349+124+58+93) = 0.7580128. For the second it is the same -   a2 = (346+127)/(346+127+61+90) = 0.7580128.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the correctly classified instances reported in the summary part (a little bit above the part it's reporting the accuracy by class). in front of this part you can see a number (which indicates the number of instances) and a percentage (which is the accuracy). 
[image]